# Spring MongoDB search id by string

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a simple spring web application which uses mongodb. I have a requirement of searching the collection id by string, where the string should work regex Statement. My criteria creating method looks like this.

```
public Criteria getSearchCriteriaQuery(String keyword, String colomnArray[]){
    Criteria[] criteriaList = new Criteria[colomnArray.length];
    for (int i=0; i<colomnArray.length; i++) {
        criteriaList[i] = Criteria.where(colomnArray[i]).regex(keyword, "i");
    }
    return this.criteria.orOperator(criteriaList);
}
```

My domain looks like this

```
@Document
public class sampleDomain{

@Id
private String id;
....
}
```

When I use "id" / "_id" as the column name, it does not return anything even if I send a valid string as keyword. example query I tried is given below

```
id in db - 560299fe627942619bcfdc87
keyword - 560
```

Is there a solution for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work I think.
A MongoDb ID is not a String but an ObjectId which can be represented as a String but not handled as one.
So doing a regex on an ObjectId would mean mongo would have to unpack every ObjectId to a String and then do the regex on it. That would be crazily inefficient.

Unless Spring-data-mongo has something up his sleeves, you might need to rethink your model and your queries.

Because this is a strange use case for MongoDB to do a regex on an ObjectId.
Can you explain why you are doing this and why you are not using another field to do the regex on?

Kind regards
Chris

Comment: This was just an example. I am querying other fields as well. This is done by adding the field names to the column array. The only issue is, this does not work for the field 'id'. Searching for the id in that way is a requirement..

Comment: As far as I know, this is not going to work. I still fail to see the reason why you would want to query on a part of a random generated value.

Comment: @DBC You fail to see why a plain string should be able to be used as the ID? Seems obvious to me. I am in the same situation. I want to use plain strings as IDs and spring makes that very difficult if not impossible (I'm still searching for the solution). But I definitely do not want to use ObjectIds to store references to objects. I want to use plain strings.